# `Cannot find module` for my own TypeScript module

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, node-modules

I have just published a new TypeScript-based module to the NPM registry, [ooafs](https://github.com/edgarogh/ooafs). However, when I try to install it and import it in another TypeScript project, VSCode gives me the following error on the import statement: `Cannot find module 'ooafs'.ts(2307)`.

This module's source files are compiled to JavaScript to a `dist/` folder and definitions (`.d.ts`) are also generated.

Here's the tree of the published module (the one we download when we `npm install`):

```
.
├── dist
│   ├── Entry.d.ts
│   ├── EntryFilter.d.ts
│   ├── EntryFilter.js
│   ├── Entry.js
│   ├── EntryType.d.ts
│   ├── EntryType.js
│   ├── FSTypings.d.ts
│   ├── FSTypings.js
│   ├── index.d.ts
│   └── index.js
├── LICENSE
├── package.json
└── README.md
```

The `package.json` does contain the following entries:

```
{
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
    ...
}
```

Because the module works normally on Runkit (pure JS), I assume the only problem I have is related to TypeScript, and it's not the first time TypeScript tells me a module doesn't exist when missing declaration files are the only problem.

Am I missing a step in the compilation process ?
Are my `package.json` properties wrong ?

If you need to see more code, the Github link is at the beginning of the question, and the published module structure can be found here: https://unpkg.com/ooafs@0.1.2/dist/.

Comment: Do you see `ooafs` in node_modules? and test requires another module that is false or success. Try close file and open(maybe you don't download and open, after that you download it)

Comment: The module _is_ downloaded (it is in `node_modules`), all other modules load without a problem and I've restarted VSCode without any improvement. The problem definitely has something to do with _my module_.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, the problem didn't come from my module (ooafs). It was a problem with the `tsconfig.json` of the project I was using the module in: The `module` property must be set to `commonjs` apparently.

**Very late edit:**
Also, I highly recommend setting `esModuleInterop` to `true` which allows you to import non-es6 modules in a more natural manner.

Comment: please explain more what you mean about commonjs.

Comment: switching to ```"module": "commonjs"``` from ```"module": "es6"``` in compilerOptions of the tsconfig.json also fixed my error, but I do not know why. Does anybody understand this?

Comment: It seems like touching `tsconfig.json` makes vscode reload the project and finally find the modules. It is not about the `commonjs` value for me, just about touching the file. I achieve the same results by pressing F1 and running "TypeScript: Reload Project".

Comment: This worked for me. I wrote a new tsconfig, tsc --init and took the parts like  "module": "commonjs", and applied it to my existing file. There's also parts in this that point to "es2017", this is an old article, but it at least got me in the right place!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not the fix, and is certainly not ideal when you have to use top-level awaits (which don't work on commonjs).

You want to make sure your import path is the final file that node will try and load. So you cannot rely on folders resolving to folder/index.js and you cannot rely on giving file names without extensions (give the ".js" extension)