# `Cannot find module` from a new owned TypeScript module

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, typescript-typings

I have juste publish a new Typescript project on NPM registry, [puppeteer-jquery](https://github.com/UrielCh/puppeteer-jquery). The code works fine.
But when I try to use it in an other project:

```sh
npm install puppeteer-jquery
```

and try to import it with:

```js
import { PageEx, BrowserEx } from 'puppeteer-jquery';
```

I get the error:
`Cannot find module 'puppeteer-jquery'.ts(2307)`

Locally, I can only use it by installing a local source copy, and importing:

```js
import { PageEx, BrowserEx } from './node_modules/puppeteer-jquery/src/setup';
```

the [package.json](https://github.com/UrielCh/puppeteer-jquery/blob/master/package.json) from pupeteer-jquery:

```
{
  "name": "puppeteer-jquery",
  ...
  "main": "lib/index.js", /* also tried with "./lib/index.js" value */
  "typings": "lib/index.d.ts", /* tried with "types" and "typings" key */
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "typescript": "^3.6.4"
  },
  "files": ["lib", "data/*.js"] /* data contains jquery.js as a ressource */
}
```

the [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/UrielCh/puppeteer-jquery/blob/master/tsconfig.json) from puppeteer-jquery:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "rootDirs": [
      "src"
    ]
  },
  "include": [ "src" ], /* added after the first post */
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "lib"]
}
```

npm publish --dry-run:

```sh
npm notice   puppeteer-jquery@0.1.5
npm notice === Tarball Contents === 
npm notice 1.1kB   LICENSE              
npm notice 410B    lib/index.js         
npm notice 280.4kB data/jquery-3.4.1.js 
npm notice 5.7kB   lib/jQueryPlugin.js  
npm notice 77B     lib/PJQuery.js       
npm notice 1.0kB   lib/setup.js         
npm notice 1.2kB   package.json         
npm notice 2.0kB   README.md            
npm notice 242B    lib/index.d.ts       
npm notice 411B    lib/jQueryPlugin.d.ts
npm notice 2.2kB   lib/PJQuery.d.ts     
npm notice 518B    lib/setup.d.ts       
npm notice === Tarball Details ===
```

This issue looks like [stackoverflow 54695891](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54695891/cannot-find-module-for-my-own-typescript-) but it's not the same.

PS:

- this is not my first Typescript project
- this project have no depencences
- I also try to include TS source and source maps into the released package, but withou more success.

Comment: After lot of test, I rebuild a new project using this dependence and it's works.

Comment: In my case the issue was that I was missing
"typeRoots": [
    "./node_modules/@types"
] within the tsconfig.json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the module and it looks like an issue with your build or publishing setup--the file `lib/index.d.ts` that `typings` points to doesn't exist in the published version.

```
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── data
│   └── jquery-3.4.1.js
├── lib
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── PJQuery.d.ts
│   │   ├── PJQuery.js
│   │   ├── index.d.ts
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   ├── jQueryPlugin.d.ts
│   │   ├── jQueryPlugin.js
│   │   ├── setup.d.ts
│   │   └── setup.js
│   └── test
│       ├── basic.spec.d.ts
│       └── basic.spec.js
└── package.json
```

Comment: Strange, but your are right... let me fix that. and see if it's works.

Comment: Fixed, but the issue is still the same with puppeteer-jquery@0.1.5

Comment: Is the tsconfig in your post the one from puppeteer-jquery or the consuming package?

Comment: from pupeteer-jquery, I add direct link to github in the question.